# Is there a word for a concept defined by the lack of something?

Tags: meaning

I have been trying to find a word that describes a concept that is only defined by the lack for something. For example, there isn't really any such thing as cold, it is a concept we use to describe the lack of heat. So is there a word to describe the kind of word that "cold" is?

Comment: One could however see things alternatively: heat could be considered as the lack of inertia keeping molecules still. Interesting idea though. I'd be curious to see if there is a way of expressing this idea in a concise fashion.

Comment: @James: Er...from a physics point of view that suggestion is not particularly well founded. Inertia doesn't *"keep [things] still"* it keeps their momentum constant, which is a different thing. The distinction between heat and cold is a good one because there is a zero for temperature, and that represents the maximum "coldness".

Comment: Here's a link to a list of what I'm happy to call 'privatives'. It's pretty substantial, even though it's actually only concerned with those starting with the Greek **a-** and **an-** prefixes, *and* has a rider pointing out that only the 'significant' words are included... http://wordinfo.info/unit/2838/ip:1

Comment: @dmckee: You're right about physics (been a while since I read through textbooks on the subject). What I meant to say is a cold objet is lacking caloric energy but it could be said to be "gaining" in terms of other properties. This is why I still feel it's a relative concept as is implied by the "lack of something", something being the point of reference.

Comment: Both *privative* and *negative* are good answers. We often have a negative definition (containing something like *not*, 
*un-*, etc.) of words that have a privative meaning (words that concern the removal or possibly the absence of something).

Comment: One might call it a "residual concept".

Comment: For me, it does not seem that *cold* can be reliably interchanged with *not hot*, *absence of hot(ness)* or anything along those lines; at least, not in casual day-to-day use. Also, the privative version of, say, *heated* would be *unheated*, or something like that, which again, I do not think is equivalent to *cold* or something similar.

Answer (score 10):

@Matt Ellen used the word *privative* in this sense in his (closed) question, *[Is the truth a privative?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/19563/5822)*

He used the word as a noun and the link from his question to the word's definition at *[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/privative)* does have this:

> **privative**
>   -*noun* something that is deprived.

I'm not sure how common this usage is. *NOAD* has this:

> **privative** |ˈpraɪvədɪv|
>   adjective
>   (of an action or state) marked by the absence, removal, or loss of some quality or attribute that is normally present.
>   • (of a statement or term) denoting the absence or loss of an attribute or quality : *the wording of the privative clause*.
>   • Grammar (of a particle or affix) expressing absence or negation, for example, the *a*- (from the *alpha privative* in Greek), meaning “not,” in *atypical*.
>
> noun
>   a privative attribute, quality, or proposition.

Comment: I'm not sure if I've heard this word before - if so, only in the context of formal logic and philosophy. Of course, this doesn't mean it isn't a good word, but I would beware of overlapping with any technical definition.

Comment: @Marcin: I seem to be familiar with this usage, though that may just be because I also read Matt's question recently. But the meaning seems pretty transparent anyway, and definitions & references abound on the net, so I'm not sure why you're wary of it.

Comment: `:-D` I was about to come and say!

Comment: Even Terry Pratchett used it ('knurd' being what you are after too much coffee and not enough alcohol IIRC), so I don't think it's too technical.

Comment: @TimLyminton: Thank you so so so so so so much. I have been looking for where I found the definition of privative that I used in my question. It's in The Science of Discworld! Which, by chance, also points out that the truth is a privative :D

Answer (score 3):

I would describe this as a "negative concept", or "negative definition", in the same fashion (and by analogy with) a negative right.

Answer (score 1):

**Via negativa** might be the word(s) you're looking for.  A quick Google search brings up: "a way of describing something by saying what it is not."  It is from Latin, normally used to describe God.  e.g. infinite is a word or concept which denies that the finiteness of something.  Per your example, cold is a concept used to describe temperature via negativa, by negating the presence of heat.

Comment: Some of the information contained in this post requires additional [references](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Please [edit] to add citations to reliable sources that support the assertions made here. Unsourced material may be disputed or [deleted](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).